# How Do I Force The User Display Name To Use The Updated Name?

Tags: office-365

When a particular user was originally created in Active Directory in Office 365 the display name was all in lower case.

A month later it was changed to Title Case. It is now several months after, yet Sharepoint and Teams still show lower case. However, Outlook and the Admin center both show the Title Case.

For instance, when the user adds a file to Sharepoint documents it is marked as modified using the lower case name and when the user is added to a list it is also shown with lower case.

The users aren't able to set their name and job title in the account overview, so why is Sharepoint still using the original display name?

How do I force it to update and use the new name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open a support case with Microsoft. This is (most likely) a backend issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try signing in again. I read about this here at https://routerforce.com/192-168-1-10/

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. This is a SharePoint and Active Directory issue and not a local router issue though.